# Place of consciousness in the Standard Model

Tags: popular-science, biology

Modern neuroscience and pharmacology has made it clear that the mind originates from the brain. No theory of physics can be complete unless it accounts for consciousness as a fundamental property arising from matter. Is there any place for consciousness in present models of physics, e.g. the Standard Model?

Comment: No, current mainstream theories have nothing to say about that.

Comment: "No theory of physics can be complete unless it accounts for consciousness as a fundamental property arising from matter." - citation needed.

Comment: No citation is needed. A complete theory would explain all phenomena. A theory that cannot account for consciousness couldn't be called complete

Comment: Physics does not yet describe the rise and fall of musical trends in nightclubs, so it seems it will not be complete anytime soon.

Comment: @StéphaneRollandin But such a phenomenon could, *in principle*, be reduced to our understanding of science. We can't say the same of consciousness.

Comment: @lemon. I wonder how one could (even in principle) model musical taste without modeling consciousness.

Comment: @StéphaneRollandin Well if the universe is deterministic then, given enough information about the world and enough computing power, you could predict such a thing. But it's unclear whether the same could be said of consciousness.

Comment: @stephane I agree. Is it a problem, though, that physics will remain incomplete for the foreseeable future?

Comment: @innisfree. Not for me; I hope it will remain incomplete forever! Who wants to exhaust Nature's mysteries?

Comment: @innisfree why do you say "a theory that cannot account for consciousness couldn't be called complete"? Do you think consciousness must be explained for a theory to predict results accurately?

Comment: Heard of AI's? This might be best answered by those who are into artificial consciousness robots..

Comment: Physics is a reductionist science. It has no obligation to worry about emergent properties built on systems that are themselves emergent properties of systems already treated by effective theories rather than directly by physics. The standard model isn't about those effective theories much less about their emergent properties.

Comment: @dmckee You're assuming that consciousness is an emergent phenomenon...

Comment: @lemon Are you proposing the existence of the thinkon?

Answer (score 11):

The goal of fundamental physics, such as the Standard Model, is somewhat reductionist: we're trying to understand the world by studying the most elementary building blocks and their interactions.

You appear to object that this approach may struggle explain more complicated emergent phenomena and experiences, such as consciousness. Certainly, it would be extremely difficult to understand most large systems, let alone a brain, in terms of their most fundamental building blocks, like quarks and electrons.

I'm not sure, though, that just because such calculations are intractable, it implies that the theory is incomplete. Rather, it suggests that it makes more sense to study phenomena with objects and quantities appropriate to that energy or length scale. For the brain that might be neurons and synapses, rather than electrons and quarks.

Comment: As another example, no-one is going to complain that physics can't be complete unless the most fundamental physics equations can be used to explain the evolution of the giant redwood tree (which doesn't involve any consciousness and presumably is ultimately a purely physical process).  Fundamental physics is the wrong level to try and explain such things. Whether consciousness needs some extra magic beyond 'mere' physics is only a question if explanations at a more appropriate level of abstraction are impossible. *Starting* at the physical level as an explanation is completely backwards.

Comment: We have good reason to believe that large, complicated physical processes (e.g. biological systems) can, in principle, be reduced to fundamental physics. However, we have no basis for such confidence when it comes to consciousness. So I think, at this point, we *can* regard the standard model as being incomplete with respect to it.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any place for consciousness in present models of physics, e.g. the Standard Model?

Searle says: probably. Penrose says: not in its present form. Chalmers and Tononi say: no, never. Dennet says: what consciousness?

---

To elaborate, here is a brief summary of modern thinking regarding how consciousness fits into the material world (as interpreted by me):

Dan Dennett regards consciousness as just a very powerful illusion that essentially requires no scientific explanation because it's not scientifically observable. He therefore dismisses the very existence of the hard problem of consciousness.

John Searle strongly disagrees with Dennett, arguing that consciousness is a part of reality, while maintaining that it can nevertheless be understood in terms of material processes. He compares consciousness to any other biological process, like digestion or photosynthesis.

David Chalmers argues that consciousness cannot be explained in terms of the material world; that even if you had complete knowledge of brain structure (at any scale) you would not be able to predict the emergence, or comprehend the nature, of qualia. Instead, he postulates that science will need to expand its axioms, possibly to include consciousness as some sort of fundamental unit of existence.

Giulio Tononi agrees with Chalmers and has attempted to put this idea on a scientific footing in his [IIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_information_theory), a theory for which Max Tegmark is a fan.

Roger Penrose suspects that consciousness can be explained in terms of the material world but that it is non-computable and will require a quantum theory of gravity to be understood.

Answer (score 0):

The question is very relevant today because of the recent advances in artificial intelligence. Various authors claim different numbers, but it is highly likely that we will have robots by 2030 with an intelligence superior to ours, if the estimates of computational power of the human brain are correct. And of course the question remains if these machines will be conscious or not.

What follows is my personal view which is line with one of the lines mentioned by lemon in his excellent answer:

As some of the comments and answers mentioned, this has nothing to to with standard model, the standard model is the minimal description from which you should be able to calculate all the other properties of the universe, including emergent ones. The only one that will remain beyond explanation is the issue of consciousness, if by consciousness you refer to the concept of qualia. Qualia is entirely subjective, say, what is the difference between our perception of blue as opposed to yellow?  nobody has yet been able to imagine an experiment that can tell if your perception of yellow is like my perception of blue and viceverza. And it is my position that this will remain so forever.  If your position is other than Dennett's (that consciousness does not exist and is just an illusion) we must accept that consciousness is just an emergent property that not only cannot be explained, but not even described. I see it as basic element of our universe, that emerges under unknown circumstances, does not influence any behavior, and thus 
will always escape any experimental measure.

NOTE: above I have assumed as (perhaps) most philosophers that qualia does not influence behaviour, any other aspects of our behaviors that are usually put in the same bag of consciousness, such as self awareness, are measurable and have a mechanistic explanation in terms of computational processes.

Comment: "The only one that will remain beyond explanation is the issue of consciousness" - while I personally share this view (most of the time), you can't claim it to be a fact...

Comment: I believe I mentioned that is my position,  just expanded in one the points of your excelent answer that I voted up

Comment: It's only relevant to people who don't have a solid definition of consciousness, which is really rooted in ethical questions: we are more likely engaged in, less reluctant and less upset about the killing of beings that we are not giving the "conscious" label by level of familiarity with ourselves. Other than that "consciousness" is a completely empty concept. You can go and ask the next best psychopath (now that's a real and testable psychiatric phenomenon) how much he cares that you are conscious.

Comment: @CuriousOne I believe we are using different definitions of consciousness, the one I am talking about is unrelated to ethic or moral, is related to qualia.

Comment: Yes, we are, I am using the only definition of consciousness that makes even remote philosophical, ethical, social and legal sense and you are using what everybody else uses, which is an undefined mess of non-workable assumptions about "it".

Comment: @CuriousOne it sad that you seem not to understand the subject at all

Comment: @CuriousOne plus you always hide behind you nasty comments and never bother to give answers, that is an easy way not to be exposed, right?

Comment: Logical thinking and empiricism do not stop at physics and science in general, they can can just as well be applied in the social sciences, and believe it or not, in philosophy. I would suggest you start thinking logically about "consciousness" before you get angry about me and my "deviant" opinions. The latter is unproductive and prevents you from attaining a higher level of knowledge.

Comment: @CuriousOne I'm unclear, do you regard qualia as illogical/unempirical?

Comment: @lemon: Is consciousness experimentally testable? Not that I am aware of, but if somebody has found a method, I would be delighted to hear it. What is empirically testable, though, is that "consciousness" is a social contract which stops those of us who sign it from killing ourselves unnecessarily. I am as much a humanist as I am a scientist, which means that I define the terms and rules under which I operate rationally. My "humane" treatment of humans and animals is based on the admission that they have internal emotions similar to mine. Bacteria, OTOH, I wipe away with bleach.

Comment: @CuriousOne Well, I am experimenting it all the time. Of course, I can't share it with you, which is problematic. But to say that it does not exist because we can't build an apparatus to measure it is just plain crazy.

Comment: As to the above answer, consciousness is not something detached from the material universe. At the very least, one person's consciousness seems to interact with his brain. So there is hope that one might be able to investigate it someday (although it _is_ possible that the interaction is one way only, who knows...). In any case, one thing we can say: there is no place anywhere in our current mathematical models of reality to embed consciousness, so obviously our theories are incomplete, as they ignore a major component of the universe (the one component through which we experience it!).

Comment: @YvanVelenik: I believe or accept that you are conscious. That's either a religious belief, if you are of that kind, or it is a legal consideration, if you are a humanist like me. I rather go with legal considerations which can be agreed on and enforced by civil contracts. The religious stuff leads to too much war and suffering. What consciousness is not, is a scientifically testable fact. Maybe one day it will be, but today we do not even have a scientifically workable definition. Since I am a scientist at heart, I can accept that. I do not have to pretend that it's science when it's not.

Comment: @CuriousOne : other people's consciousness is not (at present, at least) testable. Your own is (well, mine is constantly tested by myself, at the very least). I agree that this does not make it "scientific" at the moment. But it does not make it any less real (actually, it's the most real thing there is: all the other real things you experience are experienced through your own consciousness). (And, not that it is relevant to the present context, I am not religious.)

Comment: @YvanVelenik: What is important to you is not that we agree on what consciousness is, but that I _agree_ to honor a humanist civil contract that makes you a conscious being with human rights. Trust me, you don't want me to use any other definition, especially if your name is, as I suspect Croatian? If it is, then you know very well from first hand experience what happens when people do not honor that contract. Often enough nerdy people forget that there is more than science. There is also history and genocide and it all starts with a denial of this basic contract.

Comment: @CuriousOne What does the origin of my name have to do with the matter at hand?! This site is discussing physics. The issue was that you seem to deny existence of consciousness on the basis that there are no way to measure others' consciousness. I only claim that this is a crazy position, as you experience consciousness first-hand. All your political/social discussion has nothing to do with that. Of course, "there is more than science", but this has no place here.

Comment: @YvanVelenik: This post was never about physics to begin with and I was the first to point this out, was I not? At this point I am getting the feeling, though, that you do not even understand what I said. I didn't say that consciousness does not exist, I said that it is scientifically not approachable at this moment. I also said that the fundamental importance of consciousness is not scientific but humanist. Science without humanism, this much should be clear even to you, is a non-starter.